# How to find template text from image?

Tags: java, python, image, image-processing, artificial-intelligence

I need to process image and find from them text.
On image is ID card (passport).

Like this

[image]

For example first is name second is surname next birth date.

How can I find this areas on image maybe cut them.
For example cut photo from pass.

Actually I need detection like this:

[image]

My question is witch technology, library need I to do this?

Comment: Both witch and wizard technology will do.

Comment: OCR the complete passport and then search for keywords such as 'name' in the resulting (very messy) string.